# IIS central certificate store. How to bind CTL?

Tags: iis, certificate, iis-8, netsh, ctl

Does anyone know if you can bind a CTL to a website if it is using the central certificate store?

Normally I'd use the netsh http command to bind a CTL, but it doesn't seem to accept the sslctlidentifier switch

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh831771.aspx

Comment: Bugger. Thanks for clearing that one up!